# Having REPT function iterate over multiple values

Tags: google-sheets

Hi I'm curious if this is even possible and just thought I'd throw it out.

I have this function in google sheets:

`=ArrayFormula(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(UNIQUE('Data Validation'!B3)&",",'Data Validation'!C3),,999^99),","))))`

It allows me to specify the thing I want repeated as well as the number of times I want it repeated. Both of those are found in my data validation sheet which contains the following:

[image]

I am curious if there is a way to build the array formula so it essentially says:

`repeat each element in column B the corresponding number of times in column C`

Or in other words repeat `EVP Sales` 380 times then in the same output column repeat `VP Inside Payments` 36 times etc.

I haven't found anything remotely related to this online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you are using is already built for that scenario, just supply the needed range to calculate it properly

#### Formula:

`=ArrayFormula(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(UNIQUE('Data Validation'!B2:B4)&",",'Data Validation'!C2:C4),,999^99),","))))`

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Oh that's great! Thank you!